# Problems with If-statement condition

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm learning C, and my teacher asked my class to make a Tic Tac Toe game. I managed to make most of it, but I'm kind of stuck. I've made a function with the purpose of checking the lines, one by one, and if it finds out all the line numbers are equal to 1 or 2, the game loop receives the victory number and stops. But there seems to be something wrong with the condition I've put on the `if` inside the function, and I can't figure out what it is. It does not return a number to the game loop even when a line is complete with a number. I've tried searching for `if` conditions but I couldn't find my error.

Here's the function:

```
int checkLines (int mat [3][3])
        {

            int i;
            int victory;

            for (i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                      if ((mat [i][0] ==1) && (mat [i][1] ==1) && (mat [i][2] ==1))
                      {
                                 victory = 1;

                      } else if ((mat [i][0]==2) && (mat [i][1]==2) && (mat [i][2]==2))
                      {
                                 victory = 2;

                      }else
                      {
                           victory = 0;
                      }

            }
        return victory;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of testing each row for 1, then 2, you could simplify the test that all elements in the row are equal, then return one of the row elements: `if( mat[i][0] == mat[i][1] == mat[i][2] ) { victory = mat[i][0] }`.  Then the `else if`block is redundant (and could be used instead for the column and diagonal tests perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't `break` out of the loop once you set `victory`, which means the loop will continue and then reset `victory` to zero in the `else` part.

Actually, instead of setting `victory` and breaking out of the loop, just `return` directly, and after the loop you know you have no "victory" so you can always return `0` there.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, *even after* satisfying a *victory* condition, the `for` loop executes 3 times, essentially marking the value of `victory` to `0` in the end.

You need to stop looping once you have a match in either of the `if` statement. You can make use of a `break;` statement at the end of `if` and `else if` blocks.

Comment: Yup, fixed it! Thanks very much! =D

Answer (score 0):

Your loop always go througt all your matrix. You have to break your loop when victory is != 0. With a while instead of for you can do it.

```
int checkLines (int mat [3][3])
{
   int i=0;
   int victory = 0;
   while ((victory == 0) && (i<3))
   {
      if ((mat [i][0] ==1) && (mat [i][1] ==1) && (mat [i][2] ==1))
      {
         victory = 1;
      } 
      else if ((mat [i][0]==2) && (mat [i][1]==2) && (mat [i][2]==2))
      {
         victory = 2;
      }

      i++;
    }
    return victory;
}
```

Take notes that your code is not taking care about diagonal and vertical victories.

Comment: I fixed it =D and I made similar functions for the diagonal and vertical victories, and they are working too now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As @JoachimPileborg has already pointed out, you need to `break` out of the `for` loop if you find a victory.

Change:

```
if ((mat [i][0] ==1) && (mat [i][1] ==1) && (mat [i][2] ==1))
{
    victory = 1;
} else if ((mat [i][0]==2) && (mat [i][1]==2) && (mat [i][2]==2))
{
    victory = 2;
}
```

to:

```
if ((mat [i][0] ==1) && (mat [i][1] ==1) && (mat [i][2] ==1))
{
    victory = 1;
    break;  // found a victory - break out of loop
} else if ((mat [i][0]==2) && (mat [i][1]==2) && (mat [i][2]==2))
{
    victory = 2;
    break;  // found a victory - break out of loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int checkLines (int mat [3][3])
        {

            int i;
            int victory; /* You get it then you are happy to leave */

            for (i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                      if ((mat [i][0] ==1) && (mat [i][1] ==1) && (mat [i][2] ==1))
                      {
                                 victory = 1; break;

                      } else if ((mat [i][0]==2) && (mat [i][1]==2) && (mat [i][2]==2))
                      {
                                 victory = 2; continue;

                      }else
                      {
                           victory = 0; continue; 
                      }

            }
        return victory;
        }
```